# Python - BeautifulSoup get string from player_data

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm working on simple project and I've got a problem. I want to get string from `"div player_data="`. Here is this `div`:

```
<div id="mediaplayer60597053" 
     player_data='{
      "id": "mediaplayer60597053",
      "ads": {
        "schedule": [{
          "enabled": true,
          "counter": false,
          "skip": true,
          "click": true,
          "key": "",
          "tag": "https:\/\/www.cda.pl\/xml.php?type=g_embed&get=pool&ts=1500453286",
          "repeat": 1,
          "time": 0,
          "type": "pool",
          "displayAs": "prerol"
        }]
      },
      "video": {
        "id": "60597053",
        "file": "http:\/\/vrbx072.cda.pl\/dYXEHM8Nw3y_TZTmTs4e0g\/1500496486\/vl9afb2190473cc908d0c33cdb15bb212994083ca30c797154058bc8717c4ca746.mp4",
        "manifest": null,
        "duration": "6115",
        "durationFull": "01:41:55",
        "poster": "\/\/static.cda.pl\/v001\/img\/mobile\/poster16x9.png",
        "type": "plain",
        "width": 1920,
        "height": 816,
        "content_rating": null,
        "quality": "vl",
        "ts": 1500453286,
        "hash": "26be0bc36e8575c32ff32f4329a301889d1f6f7a"
      },
      "nextVideo": null,
      "autoplay": false,
      "seekTo": 0,
      "premium": false,
      "api": {
        "client": "json_client",
        "ts": "1500453286_60686",
        "key": "9a3859a86e909430bd379badfa68d0d712603626",
        "method": ""
      },
      "user": {
        "role": "guest"
      }
    }' 
     tabindex="1">
</div>
```

I want to get this string:

```
"http:\/\/vrbx072.cda.pl\/dYXEHM8Nw3y_TZTmTs4e0g\/1500496486\/vl9afb2190473cc908d0c33cdb15bb212994083ca30c797154058bc8717c4ca746.mp4
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need you get the div and then extract the json object from there. You can use `soup.find` to extract the div, and then use `json.loads` to convert the json string to a python dictionary.

```
import json

div = soup.find('div', {'id' : 'mediaplayer60597053' })
data = json.loads(div['player_data'])

print(data['video']['file'])
# 'http://vrbx072.cda.pl/dYXEHM8Nw3y_TZTmTs4e0g/1500496486/vl9afb2190473cc908d0c33cdb15bb212994083ca30c797154058bc8717c4ca746.mp4'
```

Comment: Thx for answer but it gives me this `uggcf://ieok056.pqn.cy/0r_FFJVYyyttw9jq-BHXmD/1500497686/uq9nso2190473pp908q0p33pqo15oo212994083pn30p797154058op8717p4pn746nqp.zc4
`

Comment: Sorry I forgot.